# Getting methods into plain file dynamically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, rubygems

I've noticed in some gems, when you simply `require 'some_gem'`, methods will appear (without any monkey patching to my knowledge). I've seen it in some gems like Sinatra, Rake, Rails, and many other helper libraries and such. How would one manage to accomplish this in ones own library?

Example:

```
require 'sinatra'

# Automatically recieve the 'get' method
get('/') { "I was monkeypatched or included automatically." }
```

If it is monkeypatching, what classes/modules are common for monkeypatching (other than String, Numeric, Array, etc).

Comment: Why do you think that they are not use monkey patching?

Comment: Could you give an example of where this is done in one of those gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinatra is essentially adding those as global methods. When you require sinatra, it [extends the Object class](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L30) with `Sinatra::Delegator` which is defined in [sinatra/base.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1705). Methods such as `get` and `put` are defined in base, and added via the delegator.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Beerlington's answer, Rails, for example, and specifically it's part ActiveSupport, uses exactly monkeypatching.

For example, declaration of `blank?` method from the ActiveSupport source (stripped):

```
class Object
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end
end
```

---

Also, very common approach to monkeypatch `Kernel` module to add methods that will be available everywhere:

```
# hello.rb
module Kernel
  def say_hello
    "Hello!"
  end
end
```

And usage of it:

```
require 'hello.rb'
 => true

say_hello
 => "Hello!"
```